# Techniques and suggestions for drawing clearly visible lines

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, line-art, autodesk-sketchbook-pro

I am looking for how to draw visible lines by using pen tablets,
I know that vector applications such as illustrator draw  visible lines (strokes) but I don't find it as comfortable as drawing in Photoshop when you use tablet.

So I have question, when you use pen tablet for drawing how do u set it to draw clearly visible lines? And what is your software suggestions (Illustrator, Photoshop, Sketchbook, or something else ...)?

This is drawn by Photoshop using pen tablet. You can see that lines aren't clear (visible).

[image]

This is drawn by Illustrator using the pen tool ([image]) but not tablet, the lines are clearly visible.

[image]

Comment: The trick is to keep your wrist locked and practice each sweep before dropping it.

Comment: @joojaa :D really ? can u explain it more :D ?

Comment: @joojaa Isn't there any vectorbased software that coloring and drawing are easier that illustartor? because coloring in illustrator is harder than coloring in Photoshop

Comment: Its allways easy to assume a better tool helps you. In reality you gain some loose some... A good carpenter does not blame his tools.

Comment: Illustrator is no more difficult than Photoshop. It all comes down to user proficiency in any application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do what you're after in Photoshop will be to draw EVERY item on its own layer and then apply a `Stroke` to it. My suggestion is to use Illustrator but don't use the Pen Tool if you're using a tablet. Try the pencil tool instead and play with the settings, I think you'll get the best results this way.

They'll still be paths too which means you can go back and refine them with the direct selection tool and/or pen tool after.

Comment: I ask different people they said its better to draw lines in illustrator then color it in photoshop